# Periodic internet connection drops

Tags: internet, connection, dsl

My setup is a dsl modem, and a dlink di 524M router.  I'm also using a Witopia VPN which runs through OpenVPN.
I've been having trouble with the internet connection dropping very frequently.  It comes back shortly, without even a router/modem/computer restart.  This happens as frequently as every ten minutes.  Occasionally (not often) it will last as long as an hour or two without dropping.  When it drops, I can get it back almost immediately by clicking Reconnect in the OpenVPN GUI and letting that do it's thing.
It's worth noting that I'm in China.  Calling support is a bit difficult because of that.  Also I don't really understand all of the router's software, although I've got it generally figured out.

I've tried a bunch of stuff, attempts to diagnose and/or fix the problem.  No success with any of the following:

I've power cycled both the modem and the router.

I've tried an ethernet connection to the router.

I've connected without the VPN.

I've disabled IEEE authentication on all connections.

I've checked for viruses.

I've tried lifting it off the ground so as to prevent overheating.

Comment: I'm having the same problem in Canada.... directly wired to my router, which is wired to the modem, which is wired to the wall...

Answer (score 1):

From your question I'm not sure what's going on. From "clicking Reconnect" I presume that is not problem with physical layer and your link between PC and router is stable. So, please do some more research with these steps:

- ping to your router = default gateway for your PC (infinitely during tests), if fails probably SW or HW problem with router (try to upgrade and then restore defaults) but check your computer too (connect some Ethernet switch and ping to another LAN host)
- ping to ISP's 1st router in the way, it could be problem with DSL link if fails
- ping your VPN remote or some another host i.e. `8.8.8.8`, if fails but 1st ISP's router is echoing, problem is on the ISP site, do traceroute to locate it
- run diagnostics from ADSL router web management and maybe really consult it with the support:

  1. it can be problem with phone wires, missing phone splitter (if calling from same line)
  2. or DSLAM (distance from you), this can ISP solve by degrading your line

Comment: oh crap, question from '09. Nevermind, hope this will be usefull for somebody else...

Answer (score 0):

> I've tried an ethernet connection to the router

If this did not resolve anything then I would probably think that it is to do with the ISP itself.

If the direct ethernet connection means you can maintain your connection, then you may be running on the same channel as someone else and interfering with each other, or that you have some other device causing interferance (Dect Phones and Microwave ovens both run on the 2.4Ghz frequency that wireless runs at).

Comment: I'm just really hoping that there's something on my side I can fix as I'm in China and dealing with the ISP is going to be problematic.

Comment: I also tried using a different channel, didn't help

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the situation is the same in China but if you have to use microfilters on your phone sockets it's worth checking that you have one in every socket that has a phone line plugged into it and try swapping them out.

Comment: I do have a microfilter on the one and only socket

Comment: It's possible it's faulty.  Out of about 100 broadband users at my company we have maybe on filter failure a year so while it's not excessive it does happen.  Plus lot's of issues with people who have cheap extensions from the main phone socket.

Answer (score 0):

many DSL routers have a setting called 'connection type'. check the WAN connection settings, most ISPs are using 'on demand' as the default setting, as opposed to 'always on' or 'nailed up' or 'manual'.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this happen whne the power dips slightly below normal and then returns.  Basically a Brownout.  Do you have reliable power?  Can you connect a UPS to smooth out power?

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you tried an Ethernet cable so it is usually not a client side problem. It could be a bad phone line in your area (soaked, bitten, something like that which does not damage the line completely) is anybody else in your area experiencing this?.